# How does object.__eq__ have access to scope of method that calls it?

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I define an object in Python 2.7 like so:

```
class C(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return object.__eq__(other)
```

equality works as one might desire:

```
In [2]: c = C()

In [3]: d = c

In [4]: d == c
Out[4]: True

In [5]: c == d
Out[5]: True

In [6]: C() == C()
Out[6]: False
```

However, when I call `object.__eq__(other)`, I am not passing `self` at all, so where is it getting it from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't have access to `self`, no, and just returns the `NotImplemented` singleton:

```
>>> object.__eq__(None)
NotImplemented
```

because `object.__eq__` is bound to the `object` *type*. Only `object` itself, if passed in, will produce a `True` result:

```
>>> object.__eq__(object)
True
```

It is used to test if *classes* are equal, not instances.

By extension, your class will return `NotImplemented` unless you pass in `object`:

```
>>> C().__eq__(None)
NotImplemented
>>> C().__eq__(object)
True
>>> C() == object
True
```

Python then asks the other object to do the equality test, and if that too returns `NotImplemented` an *identity test* is used instead.

So in the end, you could just as well have removed the `__eq__` method as it does nothing but create some extra work that leads to nothing. :-)

Comment: But why does `object.__eq__` accept only one argument instead of two?

Comment: thanks for the answer! Why not just have `object.__eq__` always return `NotImplemented`? It looks like it returns `True` or `False` explicitly whenever you pass in a subclass of object (e.g. `object.__eq__(C)` is False)